# Excel - Cumulative Quaterly savings split up in months

Tags: excel-formula

I have no clue how to get started with my problem, if anyone has an idea would be very appreciated.

Example: I have cumulative savings per quarter and I need to split it into every month. All in all i made 600 in savings. From quarter 3 to 4 I made savings of 510 and I started making savings from August onwards. Meaning that until July it is 0, August and September is supposed to be 45 and 45, Oct Nov and Dec is 170 each. Any Idea on a Formular I can use.

```
Quarter 1: 0
Quarter 2: 0
Quarter 3: 90
Quarter 4: 600
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to your screenshot, please try the following formulas:

- H2: `=IF(1 < $F$2; 0; A2 / (IF(1 >= $F$2; 3; IF(2 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H3: `=IF(2 < $F$2; 0; A2 / (IF(1 >= $F$2; 3; IF(2 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H4: `=IF(3 < $F$2; 0; A2 / (IF(1 >= $F$2; 3; IF(2 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H5: `=IF(4 < $F$2; 0; (B2 - A2) / (IF(4 >= $F$2; 3; IF(5 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H6: `=IF(5 < $F$2; 0; (B2 - A2) / (IF(4 >= $F$2; 3; IF(5 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H7: `=IF(6 < $F$2; 0; (B2 - A2) / (IF(4 >= $F$2; 3; IF(5 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H8: `=IF(7 < $F$2; 0; (C2 - B2) / (IF(7 >= $F$2; 3; IF(8 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H9: `=IF(8 < $F$2; 0; (C2 - B2) / (IF(7 >= $F$2; 3; IF(8 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H10: `=IF(9 < $F$2; 0; (C2 - B2) / (IF(7 >= $F$2; 3; IF(8 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H11: `=IF(10 < $F$2; 0; (D2 - C2) / (IF(10 >= $F$2; 3; IF(11 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H12: `=IF(11 < $F$2; 0; (D2 - C2) / (IF(10 >= $F$2; 3; IF(11 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`
- H13: `=IF(12 < $F$2; 0; (D2 - C2) / (IF(10 >= $F$2; 3; IF(11 >= $F$2; 2; 1))))`

**Note:** Cell F2 must in Date format!